# Can't program Atmega644p over ISP

Tags: arduino-ide, avrdude, isp

I am using the [Arbotix-M](http://www.trossenrobotics.com/p/arbotix-robot-controller.aspx) (Atmega644p). I am trying to program it using an [ISP from Pololu](http://www.trossenrobotics.com/p/USB-AVR-Programmer.aspx). Until yesterday, everything seemed to be working okay and we were able to upload to it without problems. However, recently our board intermittently returns the error.

> "avrdude: stk_500() initialization failed, rc =-1,
>     Double check connections and try again or use -F to override this check"

Most of the other people who get this error appear to have damaged the microcontroller in some way, but our board appears to still be functioning because it can still run the code that is already installed on it. At the moment, it basically always fails to upload, so we aren't able to change the code on the board very easily.

I have checked the voltage outputs from the device and they seem to be right. (12.5 from the main line and 5V from the auxiliary one). I don't have an oscilloscope to check the signals with, but it seems to be able to output commands fine. Thanks for reading.